# Refresh Asset Picker from javascript

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

i have to refresh the opened Asset Picker via javascript, like does the upload file interface,
any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved with SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);